# Set partitioning in ZFC

Tags: set-theory

Does $\sf ZFC$ allow the partitioning of a set by claiming that $a$ and $b$ are in the same subset if $f(a,b)$?

Cause I've once seen this technique being used in a proof but I can't see how it is consistent with the axioms of $\sf ZFC$...

Thanks in advance for taking interest in my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

It's very easy to forget, and many people do, that the axioms of $\sf ZFC$ allow parameters in the formulas used.

If $A$ is a set, and $f$ is a function whose domain is $A$, then $f$ is a set of ordered pairs, etc. etc. and $f^{-1}(u)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)=u\}$ is a definable subset of $A$, since it uses $f$ and $u$ as parameters; and this means that $\{f^{-1}(u)\mid u\in\operatorname{rng}(f)\}$ is a definable subset of $\mathcal P(A)$, using $f$ as a parameter.

You can easily verify that this is indeed a partition of $A$.

Comment: That's not really what I was asking... Suppose you wanted to partition (0,1) so that x and y are in the same subset iff x-y is rational. In your example you would have to find a function that maps all the reals in (0,1) whose difference is rational to the same element in the range. How would you do that?

Comment: I *really* don't understand your question, then. How is it different than doing it naively? You have a *set* which is the reals, another which is the rationals, another which is the subtraction operator, and you define the sets. Where do you seem to have a problem?

Comment: Can I simply have all the irrationals that have the same "suffix" in their decimal representation be in the same element of a partition of the reals? By having the same suffix i mean that there exists a natural number n so that the n+i th digit of both numbers is the same for any natural i.

Comment: Sure. If you can define it naively, using the structure of the real numbers, then you can sure as hell do it in $\sf ZFC$ which internalize all these constructions. Sure, writing it explicitly using only the language of $\{=,\in\}$ is going to be an insanely difficult and long formula. But you can prove that you can preform each step separately and conclude that you can write those formulas without a real difficulty.

Comment: Yeah, I think I finally got how to build my set. Thanks. It seemed weird at the time to be able to make a partition only knowing whether 2 elements are in the same subset or not.